# Change height and width of View with respect to seek bar changes in android

Tags: android

```
private OnSeekBarChangeListener _onSizeChangeListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
            progress = progress+MIN_POINT_SIZE;
            _view.getLayoutParams().height = progress;
            _view.getLayoutParams().width = progress;
        }
    };
```

In the above piece of code,I want to change the width and height of _view as and when user seeks to some value from Seek bar control.But _view's attributes are not changing.Could some one look into it is there any wrong going?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code in on progress changed,

```
LayoutParams newParams = new LayoutParams(progress,progress);
_view.setLayoutParams(newParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add:

```
_view.getRootView().requestLayout();
```

after you've update the `LayoutParams` dimensions.